# How can I find a new base location?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I have picked up my old savegame for No Man's Sky: NEXT, and my existing base has been archived, as per the introduction screen, and I have the following quest.

[image: Home base restoration]

So I assume I just need to find a base area with the beginning base building to restore my base. However, when I scan a planet, I can get a message telling me there is a location, but it does not show up on my radar.

[image: Base location found]

So I have no way of finding it without just flying around in circles scanning constantly. How can I accurately and easily locate a new secure base location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process for building bases has changed in the NEXT update.

**Starting a new base**
Just find a spot you like the look of and build a Base Computer. It's in the quick build menu, <kbd>z</kbd> on PC, I believe is d-pad down on a controller.

Build your case computer, and interact with it. This will kick off the process, where the game will allow you to claim the area. After this your build menu will include all your base items and you're ready to start construction.

**Recalling an existing base**
You will need to obtain Navigation Data items, either from finding them in Outposts and containers, or buying them from the Galactic Trade Network. Buy quite a few, about 30.

Go to your chosen planet and build a Signal Booster from your quick build menu. Place this and interact with it. Select the option to use 1 Navigation Data, and proceed to scan the planet for 'Habitable outposts'. Hopefully you'll see 'Shelter found' and it will be marked as 'Habitable base'.

You are looking for a Habitable Base to show up. Just keep trying until you find one. If you feel unlucky, pickup your Signal Booster, and fly to another area.

Once you've identified the spot, fly over there, and you should see a huge flat open area, just like in the Foundation update. There should be a Base Computer in the middle of the area.

Interact with this base computer and you'll be able to restore your base.

[Video for reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTbZ7RED7hE&t=3m51s)

It seems that existing bases are re-loaded 'as-is' meaning all your storage is restored as well.

[The process is detailed in this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoMansSkyTheGame/comments/91t1ml/base_computer_in_the_wild_what_is_it_and_how_to/).

Comment: I also reckon that you stand a better chance of finding an existing base computer if you do a ship scan and see the 'Suitable base site located' message, although I'm still testing this theory.

Comment: I tried 5 Habitable Bases scans after getting an 'Suitable base site located' and found 1 small settlement, 1 transmission tower and 1 drop pod. No other locations were found. So I don't think it helps, I do wonder if it just means 'a spot where you can build' and not necessarily an available base computer.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon a way to reclaim your archived base with one scan and one scan data by utilizing the new feature of uninhabited star systems.

1. travel to an uninhabited solar system (system without dominant species and without space station);
2. land on a planet that is not marked as “dead”;
3. build a signal booster and scan for habital outpost;
4. a base terminal will show up on first try.

My understanding of this is that since it is an uninhabited solar system, “habital” structures can only be “future” habitats = base terminals